# Symfony 3+: How Can I learn to use FOSRestBundle?

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to create a REST API using Symfony 3.4, but I found some difficulties to learn how to use this bundle.

So When I try to see some tutorials, I get errors due to the bundle's version shift, So I found my self trying any configuration copy and paste until it works, I feel very ugly.

I was trying to getMovies in JSON

At firsy my problem, I was getting this error:

```
There are no registered paths for namespace App
Twig_Error_Loader
```

I resolve it by adding this to config.yaml

```
fos_rest:
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
```

But after few time and whitout doing any changes a new error appears:

```
An instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface must be injected in FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandler to render templates.
```

## MoviesController.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\ControllerTrait;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
// use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use AppBundle\Entity\Movie;

class MoviesController extends AbstractController
{
  use ControllerTrait;

  /**
   * @Rest\View(populateDefaultVars=false)
   */
  public function getMoviesAction(){
    $movies = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Movie::class)
        ->findAll();

        // print_r($movies); die;
    return $movies;
  }

}
```

and when We see the doc, I ask how can I understand those lines:

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/configuration-reference.html

So My Question today is a basic question: How to learn to use a specific bundle in Symfony and to work like a professionnel ? is the problem on the bundle conceptors due to his poor documentation or on me ?

Comment: the documentation is poor but you have to clear the caches after editing the configuration and thats it, probably :) Also you can find some kickstarts on the web, check for example this fos_rest config https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/reference/api.html (only fos_rest part)

Answer (score 1):

Since Symfony 4 (Include Symfony 3.4 because it's the same thing) you should use API Platform instead FOSRestBundle

```
composer require api
```

In less than two minutes your API is ready.
Just add

`use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;` to your uses and

`@ORM\Entity` to your Entity annotations and Goo!!!

More info:

- https://symfony.com/projects/apiplatform
- https://api-platform.com/docs/core/getting-started/
- https://packagist.org/packages/api-platform/core